# QtCreator breaking my workspace

Tags: ros, qtcreator, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently, adding a package to Qt creator as shown in the [IDE wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs) and compiling it once makes it impossible to install it with catkin_make. I get the following error:

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:41 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (Permission denied):

    /usr/local/.catkin


Makefile:115: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

In the wiki, somebody wrote:

> Recently this has started to fail,
> because the main CMakeLists is a
> symlink to a non writtable location.
> The workaround is to make a copy to
> toplevel.cmake instead of using a
> symlink. And if you want the project
> to be named something else than
> "Project" then add a line at the top
> with "project(MyProjectName)"

What does this mean and how to do it?

Using Ros Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258679/qtcreator-breaking-my-workspace/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2017-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe something like this?

```
$ cp -L toplevel.cmake [project directory]
```

The `-L` flag just copies the file pointed at by a symlink, if the argument is a symlink.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2017-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0